# not able to limit vertical scroll

Tags: html, css

I tried a lot but couldn't seem what is going wrong in this page,

I want to limit the scroll bar only upto the background image i.e I just need to scroll only 10% more .

But this page:

[Click](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/141359479/spark.html)

It shows a lot of scroll area with blank space , and the rain plugin doesn't also work there.

I tried to use:

`overflow:scroll`

or

```
overflow:hidden
```

but nothing helps hidden wont let me scroll itself , but i want a little bit of scroll

However I have been able to limit my scroll on all pages except this.
Can anybody help me, and sorry for the poor english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your `rain1` and `rain2` elements:

```
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: You have just made my day.!!